# count divs with the same attribute and display the result

Tags: jquery

I am facing a problem with jquery code when trying to count DIVs with the same attribute and display the result. My code is:

```
  $(function(){
   $.each($('.single-record #product'), function(index, item) {
    if ($(item).data('record')=='1') {
        $('#product-id-1').append('('+$('.'+$(item).data('record')).length+')');
    }else if ($(item).data('record')=='2') {
        $('#product-id-2').append('('+$('.'+$(item).data('record')).length+')');
    }else if ($(item).data('record')=='3') {
        $('#product-id-3').append('('+$('.'+$(item).data('record')).length+')');
    }else if ($(item).data('record')=='4') {
        $('#product-id-4').append('('+$('.'+$(item).data('record')).length+')');
    }else if ($(item).data('record')=='5') {
        $('#product-id-5').append('('+$('.'+$(item).data('record')).length+')');
    }else if ($(item).data('record')=='6') {
        $('#product-id-6').append('('+$('.'+$(item).data('record')).length+')');
    }else if ($(item).data('record')=='7') {
        $('#product-id-7').append('('+$('.'+$(item).data('record')).length+')');
    }else if ($(item).data('record')=='8') {
        $('#product-id-8').append('('+$('.'+$(item).data('record')).length+')');
    }
});
});
```

Also I have put everything in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bvGVS/

Please help me to show a number of div with the same attribute - for example if there are 2 divs with data-record="1" it should be shown in #product-id-8 (2)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you use so much code for this? You unly need `$('#product-id-'+$(item).data('record')).append('('+$('.'+$(item).data('record')).length+')');`

Comment: Hi DSDavid98, I am new to jquery. Can you please help me to reduce it? Please feel free to do it in my jsfiddle.

Comment: It's not valid to have multiple HTML elements with the same ID (#product). Use a class instead or JavaScript may not find the correct element for you.

Comment: @becquerel He's using different `id`s

Comment: Here is a shorter version: http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/YwBVV/

Comment: No he uses the same id in the fiddle example.

Comment: @HarryFink Oh right, I see now.

Comment: Thank you DJDavid98 but is it possible to display amount of divs with the same attribute instead of (0)(0) to have (2)

Comment: HarryFink I changed IDs to classes : http://jsfiddle.net/bvGVS/3/ still no luck - it is still original code

Comment: Here is an updated version which displays the count almost properly: http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/YwBVV/1/

Comment: It look cool DJDavid98, thank you but can it display (2) just once and not repeat it. Sorry for being so stupid. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're looking to achieve, but I would suggest grabbing only the elements with data records, and then iterating through them more efficiently to get your total. You can do this using a selector, something like:

```
var counter_object = {}; // json awesome-ness...
$(function(){

    var elements = $('[data-record]');
    $.each(elements, function(){

        var element = $(this);
        var record = element.data('record');

        if (counter_object[record] == undefined)
            counter_object[record] = 0;
        counter_object[record] += 1;

    });

    // output the results however you'd like...
    // here I'm just using the status DIV container...
    $.each(counter_object, function(index, value){
        $('#status_container')
            .append('<div>Record '+ index +' has '+ value +' results(s)</div>');
    });
});
```

And here's the HTML I used:

```
<div id="record-12" class="single-record">
    <div id="product" data-record="1"></div>
</div>
<div id="record-13" class="single-record">
    <div id="product" data-record="2"></div>
</div>
<div id="record-14" class="single-record">
    <div id="product" data-record="1"></div>
</div>

<div id="status_container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code. It runs through the elements, stores the result in an object and then in a second loop it adds the numbers to the list. ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YwBVV/3/))

```
<div id="record-12" class="single-record">
        <div class="product" data-record="1"></div>
</div>
<div id="record-13" class="single-record">
        <div class="product" data-record="2"></div>
</div>
<div id="record-14" class="single-record">
        <div class="product" data-record="1"></div>
</div>

<div id="product-id-1">Product 1 </div>
<div id="product-id-2">Product 2 </div>
<div id="product-id-3">Product 3 </div>
<div id="product-id-4">Product 4 </div>
<div id="product-id-5">Product 5 </div>
<div id="product-id-6">Product 6 </div>
<div id="product-id-7">Product 7 </div>
<div id="product-id-8">Product 8 </div>
```

```
$(function(){
    var obj ={};
    $.each($('.single-record .product'), function(index, item) {
        var record = $(item).data('record');
        if ($('#product-id-'+record).length > 0) obj[record] = $('div[data-record="'+record+'"]').length;
    });
    $.each(obj,function(i, el){
        $('#product-id-'+i).append('('+el+')');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a million DJDavid98. You are a superstar!

Comment: Erg, just beat me ;) Be careful, `size()` has been [deprecated as of jQuery 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/size/)...